# Get data based on user login in laravel backpack

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, laravel-backpack

I am using backpack to created admin panel in my project. I have two types of user one is Superadmin and second is admin. I just wanted to give the permissions to superadmin as he can list,add,edit all the rows from database..

but the admin can only edit,delete and list those rows created by himself..

So please help me, I am new in laravel backpack??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the results you show in the `setup()` method of your entity's CrudController, then disallow access to update/destroy methods.

You result could look something like this:

```
public function setup() 
{
    // take care of LIST operations
    if (\Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
       $this->crud->addClause('where', 'author_id', '=', \Auth::user()->id);
    }
}
```

Additionally, you need to place checks inside your `update()` and `destroy()` methods, to not allow an admin to delete someone else's entry.

```
// place this both inside your update() and inside your destroy() method 
if (\Auth::user()->hasRole('admin') && $this->crud->entry->author_id!=\Auth::user()->id) {
   abort(405);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanx for you answer. But I just do not want to show the edit page. So where should I put this check..?

Comment: and It also showing the error -  Trying to get property of non-object at the line where I write $this->crud->entry_created_by.. plese give me a solustion